# PHP - how to get SSL key length

Tags: php, ssl, curl, fopen

I've got a script using fopen (yes, I know, but it's for legacy reasons) to retrieve details of SSL certificates. Now they want to add the SSL key length to the extract but I can't find it. I COULD refactor using CURL but there's so many variables pulled out that parsing the result will take ages. Is there any easy way to get the key length that I'm missing?

I've switched to using this to get the cert details:

```
$r = stream_socket_client("ssl://www.google.com:443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $g);
$cont = stream_context_get_params($r);
$temp = openssl_x509_parse($cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate"]);
```

Then I'm getting the data out of the array

Comment: Please add some code about the type of SSL cert you are using.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. I'm parsing a LOT of SSL certs. If it was just one I'd use a browser.

Comment: This may help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-details.php

Comment: @RobbieAverill Thanks for that. I'm using this to get the cert details. 

`$r = stream_socket_client("ssl://www.google.com:443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $g);`

Not sure how to use that function with this

Comment: Put that snippet into your question before it gets closed :)

Comment: That's the information I was asking for... we don't know what functions you can use to grab the length, if we don't know what you are implementing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $ssloptions = [
        "capture_peer_cert" => true,
        "capture_peer_cert_chain" => true, 
        "allow_self_signed"=>false, 
        "CN_match"=>$domain, 
        "verify_peer"=>true, 
        "SNI_enabled"=>true,
        "SNI_server_name"=>$domain,
        "cafile"=>'/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' //mozilla ca cert bundle: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
    ];
    $g = stream_context_create (["ssl" => $ssloptions]);
    $r = stream_socket_client("ssl://$domain:$port", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $g);
    $cont = stream_context_get_params($r);
    $key = openssl_pkey_get_public($cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate"];);
    $res = openssl_pkey_get_details($key);
    echo $res['bits'];
```

?>